# How to replicate from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, replication, merge-replication

I have SQL Server 2000 as publisher and SQL Server 20008 R2 as subscriber.

I want to replicate data from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2 on a different machine.

Primary key fields are not defined on some tables so transaction replication is not a choice.

I think merge replication is not a choice because the Subscriber SQL Server version is higher than the publisher.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you not add primary keys to those tables which are missing them?

Comment: I just can add an `identifier` filed and set it as `primary key`. Will this solve my problem for `transactional replication`?

Comment: Well, you need primary keys on all tables for any replication to work. Otherwise how are you going to know which rows have been moved over to the subscriber or not?

Comment: May I ask what the business problem that you are trying to solve is here? I'm curious to know why Replication has been chosen as the solution implementation method over other available options, which could be more suitable.

Comment: I want to have an updated version of `SQL Server2000` which is filled by windows applications in `SQL server 2008` and use it in my website. because I have used some features of `SQL server 2008` in my web site.I just can add add identity fields as primary key in tables.is this solve my problem?

Answer (score 8):

Bad news: SQL Server 2000 isn't officially supported. You're putting yourself in a situation where the link between these two servers could cause problems, and if you call Microsoft for support, you'll be out of luck.

Don't be That Guy who breaks the production server because he wanted to connect these two servers. Tell your management that SQL Server 2000 is out of support. SQL Server 2008 R2 has lots of cool features to help - rather than working with replication in an unsupported scenario, put your time into getting that old SQL Server 2000 box into a supported scenario.